# BootStrap Dropdowns Not Being Styled Properly With navbar-inverse

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to make a dropdown with the properties of navbar-inverse and on hover.  I have the on hover problem fixed, it is the navbar-inverse I can not figure out.  I have searched the internet and found if you used this code

```
.inverse-dropdown {
  background-color: #222;
  border-color: #080808;
  &>li>a{
    color: #999;
    &:hover{
      color: #fff;
      background-color: #000;
    }
  }
}
```

it would make the dropdown color what I wanted, but the text remained very hard to see.  I have tried changing the color tag to make the text what I wanted but it did not change anything.  With that code my dropdown looks like this:

[image: wrong dropdown colors]

As you can see if you look at the image, the text is hard to read.  Can someone please help me I have been trying to do this for days.

For reference this is all code that goes with the dropdown:

HTML:

```
<li class="dropdown">
        <a href="staff.html"><i class="fa fa-group"></i> Our Staff</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu inverse-dropdown text-center">
            <li><a href="http://aesny.net/aes">Employee Login</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
```

CSS:

```
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}

.inverse-dropdown {
  background-color: #222;
  border-color: #080808;
  &>li>a{
    color: #999;
    &:hover{
      color: #fff;
      background-color: #000;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey, 2.0 series or 3.0 series?

Comment: Do you mean bootstrap version, if so I am on version 3.3.1.

Answer (score 0):

I found this:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open 
.dropdown-menu {
  background-color: #222;
  color:#fff;
}
```

Also, could it be that the color you see is the "visited" version of the link? Could you post your whole navbar?

Answer (score 0):

```
.dropdown-menu.menu-inverse {
    background-color: #222;
    border-color: #080808;
}

.dropdown-menu.menu-inverse li > a {
    color: #9d9d9d !important;
}

.dropdown-menu.menu-inverse ul > li > a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #000;
}

.dropdown-menu.menu-inverse li.divider {
    background-color: #000;
}
```

This **CSS** is just compiled version of **LESS** from @CalmKai's answer (which is straight off the GitHub issue).

My apps show the username in the top navbar, so inverse for it too:

```
.navbar-inverse #appMenuUsername {
    color: #9d9d9d
}
```